# How to optimize pre-processing json to dataframes for this case

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpgw5.png)

In order to change each data from json to dataframe as above, I wrote a code like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
with open('color.json', 'r') as f:
    json_color = json.load(f)

df=pd.DataFrame(json_color)
start = time.time()
new_df=pd.DataFrame()
index_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    for j,(key,value) in enumerate(df['result'][i]['RGB'].items()):
        key=key.split(',')
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[key[0],key[1],key[2],value]])
        index_list.append(df['result'][i]['name'][:-4]+'_'+str(j))
        new_df=pd.concat([new_df,df2])
new_df.index=index_list
new_df.columns=[['R','G','B','percentile']]
print(new_df)
print(time.time()-start)
```

It actually works, but I wish I could change these codes to peform more efficiently.
Is there any advice for here?

Comment: What is `df['result']`?

Comment: i read json file and saved it to dataframe, the dataframe had two columns. first column contains name for each images ('~.jpg') and second column contains each RGB ratio+percentile for each color ( for example for 1 jpg, there can be 3 colors which mean 3 RGB Value for each)

Comment: I mean there is no reason to have a `'result'` column name with your data except if your json is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simpler to solve the problem with python data structure then convert the result as DataFrame:

```
name = json_color['name'].rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0]
data = {}
for j, (vals, P) in enumerate(json_color['RGB'].items()):
    R, G, B = vals.split(',')
    data[f'{name}_{j}'] = [int(R), int(G), int(B), P]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, columns=['R', 'G', 'B', 'percentile'], orient='index')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                R    G    B  percentile
vogue_S_21_fashion-east_56_0   23   23   23       81.73
vogue_S_21_fashion-east_56_1  104  108  109       17.11
vogue_S_21_fashion-east_56_2  223  228  233        1.01
vogue_S_21_fashion-east_56_3  142  134   82        0.15

>>> json_color
{'name': 'vogue_S_21_fashion-east_56.jpg',
 'RGB': {'23,23,23': 81.73,
  '104,108,109': 17.11,
  '223,228,233': 1.01,
  '142,134,82': 0.15}}
```

However if your `json_color` looks like:

```
>>> json_color
{'result': [{'name': 'vogue_S_21_fashion-east_56.jpg',
   'RGB': {'23,23,23': 81.73,
    '104,108,109': 17.11,
    '223,228,233': 1.01,
    '142,134,82': 0.15}}]}
```

You can use:

```
data = {}
for record in json_color['result']:
    name = record['name'].rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0]
    for j, (vals, P) in enumerate(record['RGB'].items()):
        R, G, B = vals.split(',')
        data[f'{name}_{j}'] = [int(R), int(G), int(B), P]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, columns=['R', 'G', 'B', 'percentile'], orient='index')
```

Comment: thanks for your advice even though I leaved poor explanation. I would try it and come here later.

Comment: @DuwonLim. I updated my answer because I think your json file has only one key ('result') and this is a list of dict. Can you check it please?

Comment: Yes, json file is  just same as you expected.  Because there is too much data, I changed len(df) to 10 in order to check if it works properly. My code worked properly. Your suggestion looks reasonable but it works for only last element from original json file.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. Can you try my updated code, please?

Comment: It works and much faster. I will study on your code. Thank for your kindness